# Firebase Realtime Database Show Users Name - Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have to show data belonging to a user that logged in.

My database structure is as follows:

```
Users/Drivers/Uid/name,phone...
```

How can I show the data of a user that logged in by using JavaScript?

Comment: Hi Michael, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you provide us with more detail and code examples. so other users can help you better?

Comment: Hi, I want to show that username of logged in as a text in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a structure like that, you can display all data for the currently logged in user with:

```
var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var userRef = firebase.database().ref("Users/Drivers").child(currentUser.uid);
userRef.on("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

Comment: I want to show that username of logged in as a text in html .

Comment: OK. That's a two-step process: 1) create a HTML structure, 2) update that where I now have a `console.log`.

Comment: I changed from  console.log to         document.getElementById("name").innerText=snapshot.val(); But It is not working.